# The `start` program opens a new window

Tags: batch-file

Whenever I want to run my EXE file with the `start` command to prevent Batch from waiting, a new window opens.
I would like this to not happen.

My OS is Windows 10 x64, though I need this to work in at least Windows 7.

Here is my Batch file:

```
@echo off
start /B "gamebatch init"
gamebatch setvar t 5
set /p theVar=<%TEMP%/GAMEBATCH
echo %theVar%
pause
gamebatch exit
```

GameBatch is a program I made.
`gamebatch init` creates a server.
Other `gamebatch` commands contact the server with a command.
If a value is outputted, then GameBatch put's it into `%TEMP%/GAMEBATCH`.

Comment: Try `start /B`?

Comment: It does not open the console anymore but for a strange reason it does not exit even with `exit` (My Batch file).

Comment: post the batch file then!

Comment: @Compo Added the code

Comment: `start` launches a separate command process.  `exit`ing the current process will not close the launched process. I am assuming your `gamebatch exit` command handles closing the launched process. Are you saying that the final `exit` does not close the original window?

Comment: What kind of program is gamebatch? Is it a batch file?

Comment: @ThomasWeller `gamebatch` is an EXE file.
@RemyLebeau I was trying to use `exit` because if using `start /B` then the batch command console does not close. `exit` does not work anyways so I'll remove that.

Comment: Is gamebatch a 32-bit GUI executable? Can you invoke gamebatch init without 'start'? You appear to be using gamebatch with other instructions just fine without start!

Comment: GameBatch uses 2 DLLs, one for 32-bit programs and the other for 64-bit. It is not a GUI executable, it does not output anything at all. The problem is that when not using `start`, then Batch just waits until the server quits (Which does not happen until using `gamebatch exit`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using both **Start** with **cmd.exe** then?

```
@Echo off
Start /B Cmd /C gamebatch init
gamebatch setvar t 5
Set /P theVar=<%TEMP%/GAMEBATCH
Echo %theVar%
Pause
gamebatch exit
```